# get the new selectedValue of the listBox using the OnSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, selectedindexchanged

I have a listBox in a asp.net web form. OnLoad i add items to the listbox and i add a OnSelectedIndexChanged event handler:

```
public void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\log.txt");

    sw.WriteLine(listBox.SelectedValue);

    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
}
```

The stream writer is so i can see the output...

I have AutoPostBack set to true on the listbox but everytime i select a new item it reloads the page but the print out is always the first item in the list instead of the item i clicked on.  Anyone have an idea of what im doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnLoad runs every time the page is loaded. Check `Page.IsPostBack` to make sure you are only adding items to the list the *first* time you load the page. i.e.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) { FillMyListbox(); }
```